# I'm not getting a correct value of my object list

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the TYPEHEAD for my input with the library [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples), to show the list of objects (just like a select without a box):

**HTML**

```
<input type="search"
       #instance="ngbTypeahead"
       placeholder="Search"
       aria-label="Search"
       [(ngModel)]="model"
       [ngbTypeahead]="search"
       [resultTemplate]="rt"
       [inputFormatter]="formatter"
       (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
       (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
>
```

When I'm writing a name of my object I'm only getting `empty value` seven times (all objects that I'm waiting for) if I choose an object the value on the input appears correctly (but in the box it's empty).

**TS**

```
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      merge(this.focus$),
      merge(this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()))),
      map(term => (term === '' ? this.productList
        : this.productList.filter(v => v.name_product.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );

   formatter = (x: {name_product: string}) => x.name_product;

    searchUrl(url){
      if(url){
        window.open(url,'_blank');
      }
    }
```

**JSON**

```
  productList =
  [ 
    {
        id_product:1,
        name_product: 'Laptop Dell'
    },
    {
        id_product:2,
        name_product: 'Laptop HP'
    },
    {
        id_product:3,
        name_product: 'G-Shock Casio'
    },
    {
        id_product:4,
        name_product: 'Casio LR-T CALC'
    },
    {
        id_product:5,
        name_product: 'LG G3 Stylus'
    },
    {
        id_product:6,
        name_product: 'DYMO 450 Turbo'
    },
    {
        id_product:7,
        name_product: 'Brother QL 700'
    }
  ];
```

But, I need to show the name of my product `(name_product)`, but in my `[(ngModel)]="model"` I hope to get the id `(id_product)`. How can Fix this bug?.

Here it's my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typehead-ng-bootstrap?file=src/app/app.component.ts) of this bug.

Comment: can you create a stackbliz please?

Comment: Yes, check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typehead-ng-bootstrap?file=src/app/app.component.ts)!

Comment: in your input change the `type="search"` to  `type="text"`

Comment: let me check your code. give me a few

Comment: check this also:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was in the **Html**

Also, im showing you how can you get the `id`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrftun

```
 <label for="typeahead-basic">Search :</label>

<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <div (click)='getId(r.id_product)'>{{r.name_product}}</div>
</ng-template>

  <input id="typeahead-template" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt"
  [inputFormatter]="formatter" />

  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" (click)="searchUrl(model.url)">Search</button>

  <pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>

  Id: {{id}}
```

**TS**

```
 getId(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but only in the first time (after you choose the object you get the id, but if you want to change the product, you get the firs id, no change), maybe using an event can works?

Comment: Click on it with your MOUISE. Not with the arrows or nor by clicking enter. the method is on click. If you want to use the enter you can do that by doing (keypress) etc

Comment: ohh yes, that's right. I'm so tired jaja I couldn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: jajaj you good parce! I had fun answering this. Never used the typehead before

Comment: also you can combine both the (click) and the (keypress) etc in the same div ;)

Comment: Hey bro, I've found that in a explorer as Mozilla the click event doesn't work, if I use it on Chrome I don't have any problem with that. Can you help me, again ?

Comment: @jecorrales. Let me try on my computer using firebox. Sounds like a polyfill issue.

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have?

Comment: I'm using the Firefox Developer with Version 63.0b9 and the Mozilla Firefox Version 62.0, in both doesn't work (to get the ID with click event)

Answer (score 1):

change this line as following within `<ng-template>`

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <ngb-highlight [result]="r.name_product" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight> 
   //or just to see the item you can use {{r.name_product}}
</ng-template>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typehead-ng-bootstrap-gajnfb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks, it works to show the products list. But how can obtain the id for the product selected and not the name (just like when we use the `<option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id_product">
                      {{ product.name_product}}
                    </option>` in a select list for html

Comment: there is an option in it's [API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api) . check that

Comment: use id field in  `(click)="searchUrl(model.id_product)"`